# When should exceptions be documentated?

Tags: php, phpdoc

Assume the following snippet:

```
public function foo() 
{
    return $this->dependency->bar();
}
```

If `dependency::bar()` is known to throw an exception, but `foo()` is not expected to handle it. Should `foo()` have an `@throws` entry in it's docblock? Or should this be implicit? The phpdoc documentation is somewhat vague about this.

Assuming that `dependency` is injected based on an interface; should the interface document that the method *can* throw the specified exception.

Does it matter if the exception should be handled by the calling code or is that irrelevant to the situation?

Semantics all the way :)

Comment: In other languages (java) is mandatory to explicitly define which exceptions are thrown (and not handled) in the body of the function. It may seem a little bit of a pain if you handle the exception far up the call stack, but adding information can't hurt. (In this specific case, as you said, foo is not handling the exception, and foo doesn't know if the caller will be handling it, so, according to foo, it should be noted)

Comment: Since `$this->dependency->bar()` is an internal implementation detail that the caller and/or peruser of the documentation cannot/should not know about, documenting the exception is the only way to make it catchable.

Comment: btw if you use PhpStorm - IDE will encourage you to have such exceptions in @throws entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created public function (everyone can use it) which in some case can throw exception - hence you definitely have to have `@throws` entry in your docblock.

If exception throws from your dependency - it's your internal implementation and it's encapsulated - hence someone who will use your function will have no idea what expect from your function.

In case of interface injection - interface must describe all exceptions because exceptions it's part of behavior of class and interface must describe all possible behaviors.

In case you have `try-catch` block and handle all exceptions from dependencies - you have to have only your own exceptions in `@throws` entry in your docblock.

Comment: Would you, for clarification, catch and rethrow the error?

Comment: @Timo Yes, you can do it and you have to describe your exception in `@throws` block.